# How to make 3 images in a 1x2 form in flexbox with the 2 equaling the height of the first?

Tags: flexbox

So I want to make 3 images over 2 columns. The left image will be 100% of the height of the flexbox and I want to 2 right side images to be stacked top to bottom and their total height to equal the height of the left image or the flexbox height itself.  When responsive resizing I want to keep this ratio as well.

The problem I'm having now is that upon resizing the left image shrinks and the combined height of the right 2 gets larger than the left image.

Thanks for trying to understand my jibberish.

I've tried a number of things and nothing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Flexbox

In order to accomplish what you are describing using flexbox you will need to use two flexboxes which will require making a few changes to the HTML.

1. The outer flexbox should have `flex-direction: row;` (this is the default value so it can be omitted). This will flex its children horizontally.
2. The inner flexbox should have `flex-direction: column;`. This will flex its children vertically.

The children of the first div should have `flex: 1;` which will distribute the space using an even ratio amongst the children.

You then just need to set `height: 50%;` for each of the images in the second flexbox.

Here's an example of what your code could look like:

```css
.container,
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

img,
div {
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right>img {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?mountain">
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?city">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?cat">
  </div>
</div>
```